# How to disable mipmap atlas generation in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

When I add my game images to an atlas, the game's bundle size explodes fourfold.

Even with the RGB565_COMPRESSED setting I see a drastic increase in bundle file size. When I just add the image files to the Xcode project without generating an atlas, the bundle file size is a lot smaller.

My images in the atlas folder are 128x128 tiles only.

I suspect that Xcode is generating a lot of mipmap atlasses that I don't need for my game because there are no zoom levels. How can I suppress that or reduce atlas file size further?